# jQuery plugin DataTables API function fnFilterAll

Tags: jquery, plugins, filter, datatables, html-table

I'm trying to use the jQuery DataTables plugin downloaded from here,
http://www.datatables.net/index
and it works pretty well, however, for my website I need to be able to filter words in all the tables on my page with one search box. There is an API plugin to do this detailed here,
http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnFilterAll
but I'm not sure how to use it in my site. I don't understand the example and am hoping someone can help me out.

I need to know what to reference in my script/script statement and how to implement it with my existing tables. Here's what my js code looks like...

```
var oTable =  $("#myTable").dataTable( 
            {
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": true,
            "bSort": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "bAutoWidth": false
            });
```

And here's what one of my tables looks like...

```
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="myTable"> 
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ALBUM</th>
                    <th>SONG</th>
                    <th>LENGTH</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="album">The Unraveling</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>"Alive and Well"</td>
                    <td>2:06</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>"My Life Inside Your Heart"</td>
                    <td>3:02</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>"Stained Glass and Marble"</td>
                    <td>1:36</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>"Everchanging"</td>
                    <td>3:47</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>"Faint Resemblance"</td>
                    <td>2:51</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>_________________</td>
                    <td>__________</td>
                    <td>_____</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td id="year">Click album art to buy!</td>
                    <td><a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/the-unraveling/id291793862/"target="_blank"> <img src="images/the_unraveling.jpg" alt="The Unraveling" style="width: 100%;"> </a></td>
                    <td id="year">Total
                    <br>
                    Length 36:40</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to add a filter method like

```
$('#myTable_filter input').keyup(function(){
    oTable.fnFilterAll(this.value);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hPtxF/1/)

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work, keep in mind that I have multiple tables, not just the one. I'm also wondering if I can keep the same id for all of my tables so my js doesn't look like this,
    var oTable =  $("#myTable, #myTable2, #myTable3, #myTable4, #myTable5, #myTable6").dataTable(
 and this 
 $("#myTable_filter input, #myTable2_filter input, #myTable3_filter input, #myTable4_filter input, #myTable5_filter input, #myTable6_filter input").keyup(function(){
     oTable.fnFilterAll(this.value);

Comment: you want to filter accross all the tables

Answer (score 0):

You should really give each table a class such as .datatable. That would allow you neatly address and loop all your datatables :)

```
//array to contain all datatables
var aoTables = [];

//settings for the dtatables
var dataTableSettings = {
  "bPaginate": false,
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "bFilter": true,
  "bSort": false,
  "bInfo": false,
  "bAutoWidth": false
};

//loop all targeted tables in the dom to instantiate datatables
$('.datatable').each(function() {
  var oTable = $(this).dataTable(dataTableSettings);
});

//now tell the search  what tables to filter by looping the datatables array
if ($('input#search').length) {
  $("input#search").keyup(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < aoTables.length; i++) {
      aoTables[i].fnFilterAll(this.value);
    }
  });
}
```